# Avoid EMI in power circuit controled by MCUs

Tags: microcontroller, emc, solid-state-relay

This is a toy project just for fun.

As anybody knows, if I want to control a lamp by a simple switch, the circuit is as follows:

[image: Basic circuit]

However, I want to change the circuit so I can control a lamp with a push button read by a MCU.

I know that I need a SSR (solid state relay) to control the lamp 
and a MCU that reads the push button and toggles the SSR.

So, from the wall box to the lamp I have 220V AC.
From the wall box to the push button I will have 5V DC (I know that I'll need a power supply AC/DC inside the wall box).

The second step of my project is to link all MCUs in all wall boxes so I can switch on/off a lamp of another room remotely.

My question is: knowing that all the wall boxes all linked by the power line of 220V AC (Europe) and all MCUs are 5V DC can I have interferences in the 5V DC line induced by the 220 AV power line?

If yes, how can I avoid them ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you positive that all MCUs are 5V? The UK is part of Europe and it uses 230V BTW.

Comment: The MCUs I will use are ALL 5V (I work with MCUs a while ago). Concerning with the AC Volts, in MY country we had both 110V AC and 220V AC about 70 years ago (in the time of my grandfather). I don't remember myself to have another volts other than 220V AC. BTW 230 or 220 is that a HUGE difference? By my calculations this is about 1% of difference. If you can ANSWER my question, I'll appreciate.

Comment: Not 100% sure I follow what you are asking but it sounds like you want to know if fluctuations in the 220v mains are going to affect your 5V to your MCUs. Is that correct? Or are you asking if there will be some problem having all the MCUs communicating with eachother?

Comment: 4.5% difference.

Comment: @Andyaka thank you for your extremely precise calculations. 10V out of 220V is a HUGE difference!!!! However my question still has NO answer.

Comment: @BrandenBoucher: what I don't know is if I mix in the same tubes power lines (220V) with signal lines (5V) I run the risk of nothing works. So the second part of what you said is correct: I'm asking if there will be some problem having all the MCUs communicating with each other, sharing the same tubes with power lines.

Comment: @CurtoCircuito, ok, one other question then. Are you using separate communication wires from MCU to MCU for communications, or trying to use the 220v ac lines to send data?

Comment: Of course I can answer your question but my problem is that if you can't calculate the percentage difference between 220 and 230 how would you understand the details of my answer and how would you judge the best answer if several are given.

Comment: @BrandenBoucher: I'm using separate lines for power and data, but using the same "wall tracks" (plastic tubes inside the walls)

Comment: @Andyaka: 230/220 = 1,0454545454545454545454545454545 = 4,54545454545454545454545454545% are you satisfyed now? Now... can you please answer my question (if you want/can)?

Comment: @CurtoCircuito, aah. So your question is about EMI from the power lines to your data lines, as they will run physically close to each other in parallel. It could cause an issue and it would be better if you could use shielded wire for your data lines. It really depends on the length of the run, and the speed at which your communicating, then. If you have a slow speed connection (say < 10kbps), you probably wont have to worry about EMI too much. Best way to check is run the data cables, connect them to the MCU on one end and an o-scope on the other and see what the peak to peak reading is.

Comment: @BrandenBoucher: you GET THE POINT. It's exactly what you saying: power lines that run in parallel with data lines. So I thank you for your answer. You are very helpful and I will follow your advises. Thank you again.

Comment: @CurtoCircuito, Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't hesitate in buying small radio receiver modules that can fit in (or be very local to) the switch and dispence with all the clumsy control wiring. I'd have a centralized transmitter (or maybe even two if distances/reception were poor in a certain area of your home).

The minute you start trying to put wires down the existing conduits you are opening a can of worms with respect to safety of people and potential fire hazards if you don't choose the correct rated cable. That cable would/should need to be twisted pairs that are screened to prevent the high impedance of the SSR being triggered by glitches on the AC and induced current in the control wires.

But you can buy these so why waste your time trying to do it yourself: -

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Better late than never :-) Now... why don't you start to answer this at the very beginning?  You save your time and mine avoid the 4.5% and the 230V issues. However, thank you for your answer, and the next time, please, try to be less "pedantic" (no offense). BTW: British politicians often consider UK outside Europe (pound vs euro; mile vs km, pound vs kg, gallon to liter, left side drive vs right side drive, etc., etc., etc.)

Comment: I'll be as pedantic as I want LOL.

Answer (score 0):

There will probably be some interference caused by the different voltage levels you will be working with. You might want to try using optical isolation circuitry to ensure there is electrical connection between the MCU and the relay.

Source: https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/RelayIsolation

Comment: Thank you for your link. I'll appreciate your answer both because you point me useful information and because you don't lost yourself with negligible issues as other do. I want to upvote you but I get «Thanks you for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.»

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!